# URL Redirection is not working (Django 3.0)

Tags: python, django

I am the newbie of writing programming, now I am learning django.
I have a problem for URL redirection. I create the model and it does work at admin site.
Also I set the PK for each article, that successfully generate the URL by PK.
However when I post the message form the front-end, after posting it appear the error message suppose it should be redirect to the page of `DetailView`and
I have imported the reverse function in my model, but it seem not working. 
My python version : 3.7.6 and django version : 3.0.0

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /add/
No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.
```

```
My View
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from .models import Page


class PageListView(ListView):
    model = Page
    template_name='home.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_post_list'

class PageDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Page
    template_name='post.html'

class PageCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Page
    template_name='post_new.html'
    fields = ['title', 'author', 'body', 'body2']
```

```
Model

from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField


class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',  
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
    body = RichTextField()
    body2 = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post', args=[str(self.id)])
```

```
URL
from django.urls import path
from .views import PageListView, PageDetailView, PageCreateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/', PageCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('', PageListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>/', PageDetailView.as_view(), name='post'),
]
```

Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your indentation is the problem here. Fix it by:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',  
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
    body = RichTextField()
    body2 = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', args=[self.id])
```